# Can I partially color a bar based on percentage complete on a temporal axis?

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I am trying to create a Gantt chart and I want to color a single task with two colors, based on a percentage complete. Say, make the complete part green and the remaining part orange.

How can I achieve this?

Below is a sample code, also available in the editor [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAItgMYBOAlgA5TkD2AdvCACoRYDWABAIwgA0IAMoxSUJgCYADOIDMAWkncFAVn4gAovTATp8xXO6S1ABQyliGejCgZOxWgFtKKDDfiSAvn0IkK1OoxwLGxc4mrCEKI6sgpKimqa2kFSMfrcqgKm5pbWtvZOLm5wAOzKXj5YZFQ0DEysHJwy4SJiybqxsQla0XpxTZlmFlbQeY7Orhjwhp4Aul4gKBAAnmZ4oA6R7EwARpFqlvZg5PQA5vCgS+cgAGbkGChJIESVfjWMAlBLlJNBtKRH9FQaiwMGIWzg9DQKBQ8wAHldbvdHhEoh8vj8QDYnH8gXCwggbncHkxEmpPt8mFjKDiUCAPPS5kA).

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Description": "Task 1", "Start": "2023-01-05", "End": "2023-01-10", "Percentage complete": 0},
      {"Description": "Task 2", "Start": "2023-01-01", "End": "2023-01-15", "Percentage complete": 75},
      {"Description": "Task 3", "Start": "2023-01-01", "End": "2023-01-03", "Percentage complete": 100}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Description",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "stack": null
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Start",
          "type": "temporal"
        },
        "x2": {
          "field": "End",
          "type": "temporal"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected result should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ahqY.png).

I tried looking at folding, transforming, and scale. But as I am new to Vega-lite, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Reshape your data upstream. Your partially coloured bars should be rendered as two bars stacked - one for incomplete and one for complete.
2. Use Reactive Geometry as described [here](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/). This may need Vega rather than VL.

Here it is using reactive geometry.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "width": 200,
  "style": "cell",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source_0",
      "values": [
        {
          "Description": "Task 1",
          "Start": "2023-01-05",
          "End": "2023-01-10",
          "Percentatecomplete": 0
        },
        {
          "Description": "Task 2",
          "Start": "2023-01-01",
          "End": "2023-01-15",
          "Percentatecomplete": 0.75
        },
        {
          "Description": "Task 3",
          "Start": "2023-01-01",
          "End": "2023-01-03",
          "Percentatecomplete": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_0",
      "source": "source_0",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "toDate(datum[\"Start\"])", "as": "Start"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "toDate(datum[\"End\"])", "as": "End"},
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "(isDate(datum[\"Start\"]) || (isValid(datum[\"Start\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"Start\"])))"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {"name": "y_step", "value": 20},
    {
      "name": "height",
      "update": "bandspace(domain('y').length, 0.1, 0.05) * y_step"
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "layer_0_marks",
      "type": "rect",
      "style": ["bar"],
      "from": {"data": "data_0"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "#4c78a8"},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "Start"},
          "x2": {"scale": "x", "field": "End"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "Description"},
          "height": {"signal": "max(0.25, bandwidth('y'))"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "layer_0_marks"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "fill": {"value": "red"},
          
          "width": {"signal": "(datum.x2 - datum.x) * datum.datum.Percentatecomplete"},
          "height": {"signal": "max(0.25, bandwidth('y'))"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "time",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "fields": ["Start", "End"]},
      "range": [0, {"signal": "width"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "field": "Description", "sort": true},
      "range": {"step": {"signal": "y_step"}},
      "paddingInner": 0.1,
      "paddingOuter": 0.05
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "gridScale": "y",
      "grid": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(width/40)"},
      "domain": false,
      "labels": false,
      "aria": false,
      "maxExtent": 0,
      "minExtent": 0,
      "ticks": false,
      "zindex": 0
    },
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "Start, End",
      "labelFlush": true,
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(width/40)"},
      "zindex": 0
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "orient": "left",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "Description",
      "zindex": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The first solution turned out to be way easiest, so I went for that one. The second one, besides being over my head, also results in two shapes, each having their own tooltip in PowerBI, which I was trying to avoid. It turns out it is not such a problem at all. Much obliged!